# JavaScript syntax madness - anyone knows the background why this happens

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am kinda lost on why the following code does what it does the way it does.

For the following expression I would expect 1 as result, since on the right side of a literal we actually have an obj.

Expression:

```
> { a : 1 }.a
```

result Chrome:

```
Syntax error: Unexpect token .
```

result NodeJS

```
1
```

(Another question: why nodejs and chrome differs on this (and on the following))

While the expression itself has a syntax error assigning it to a variable still works.

```
> var x = { a : 1 }.a; x;
```

result:

```
1
```

Now using eval around the expression does work in Chrome and in NodeJS

```
> eval({ a : 1 }.a)
```

result Chrome and Node

```
1
```

Now using eval and the string based expression *neither* platform works

> eval("{ a : 1 }.a")

result Chrome:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
```

result NodeJS:

```
... //REPL waits more code
```

And finally the parenthesis solves it all but why?

```
> eval("({ a : 1 }.a)")
```

Result:

```
Works everywhere
```

Comment: Try a just a parents (no eval): `({ a : 2 }.a)` // 2

Comment: yeah that works. actually eval pretty much behaves as a regular function that provides an expression context in its param (in the light of the correct answer below)

Comment: @PeterAronZentai `eval` code always runs in statement context, that's why you need `eval("(" + code + ")" )` to run the code in expression context. For example if `code` is `"{a:1}"`, then what will be evaled is `"({a:1})"` because of the concatenated parenthesis.

Comment: yeah, but if inside the eval(...) we are in statement context, then how comes that this actually runs in Chrome:  eval({ a : 1 }.a) having said that in statement context {} denotes a block.

Comment: @PeterAronZentai because that's not a string. `eval` only takes a string. If you pass a non-string, it will be converted to string before evaled. So `String({ a : 1 }.a)` is `"1"` and `"1"` is `evaled` as code.

Comment: ahh yeah.. I see this now. since the conversion switches into expression mode, right?

Comment: @PeterAronZentai the conversion doesn't switch anything, you passed an invalid argument and it's converted to string. You will end up with string `"1"`, and the code is therefore just `1`. The result of evaluating `1` as javascript code is `1`. :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`eval` takes a string, so calling `eval({ a : 1 }.a)` is the same as `eval("1")`.

In statement context, `{}` delimit a block, not an object literal. You can go in expression context by using `()` as a grouping operator.

So:

```
{ a : 1 }.a
```

Is actually a block, label, numeric literal and dot-access on nothing:

```
{
   a:  1
}

.a
```

Node REPL actually runs in an expression context to begin with, but that's unusual. They run your code like `eval("(" + replInput + ")")`

Comment: yeah, this makes it crystal clear. and the main difference is in the implementation of the thing we perceive as a console prompt. and of course the clear distinction between statement and expression context and the role of the parentheses to switch is the real knowledge. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try `({ a : 1 }).a`
This will also work everywhere as the code in round bracket is executed first and then `.a` of that object is extracted.

```
`{ a:  1 }`
```

is just a block and doesn't return anything for the `.` operator to work on but enclosing it in `()` does return an object of which `.a` is extracted